# Why does a custom bash prompt show up before output is done?

Tags: bash, terminal, command-prompt, prompt

I customized my bash prompt (just added some colors and an emoji cause why not) in `~/.bash_profile`.  Works fine except when I do things like `rails generate ...`, I get long lists of deprecation messages, and the custom prompt will show up in the middle of them.  Didn't happen before the customization.

My `~/.bash_profile` contains the following:

```
export PS1="\[\e[0;35m\][\u] ~> \w\[\e[m\]\]  $>"
```

I've seen many posts about how to customize the prompt, as well as how to get bash to wait when executing specific scripts, but this isn't a script I wrote, it's just a bunch of warnings / errors.  Any way to fix this?

Comment: please show how your $PS1 is defined. do you mean you included "rails stuff" in $PS1?

Comment: @APizzle: _doing rails stuff_ is not exactly a precise description of what has been done to get the effect you see. In particular, most _rails stuff_ is done in the rails console, which is basically irb, and it is not clear at which point your bash kicks in.